# combining zip and map operations in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I understand `map` and `flatten` operations can be combined into `flatMap`, and `filter` and `map` into `collect` in Scala.

Is there anyway I can combine `zip`/`zipwithIndex` with `map`  operation?

Comment: `for ((x,y) <- xs zip ys) yield x*y`  you can use for comprehension

Comment: This does zip once and map once. I want to combine those operations

Answer (score 2):

There is no single operation in the standard library, as far as I know, but there is an extension method on various tuples, called `zipped`. This method returns an object which provides methods like `map` and `flatMap`, which would perform zipping in step with mapping:

```
(xs, ys).zipped.map((x, y) => x * y)
```

This object also is implicitly convertible to `Traversable`, so you can call more complex methods like `mkString` or `foldLeft`.

Answer (score 0):

If, for some reason, you really wanted a combined version you could write one yourself.

```
implicit class SeqOps[A](s: Seq[A]) {
    def zipWithIndex2[A1 >: A, B >: Int, That](f: (A, Int) => (A1, B))(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Seq[A], (A1, B), That]): That = {
        val b = bf(s)
        var i = 0
        for (x <- s) {
            b += f(x, i)
            i += 1
        }
        b.result()
    }
}
```

Call it like:

```
s.zipWithIndex2 {
    case (a, b) => (a + "2", b + 2)
}
```

I'd really think about this twice though and most likely go with any of the other approaches that have been suggested.